# display: flex; inconsistently displaying elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3YVLVUevHEe3tqRwH5Tc?p=preview) Plunker that has the following markup:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="block-group" draggable="true" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="block-operator">And</div>
        <div class="block-children">
          <div class="block-group" draggable="true" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="block-operator">And</div>
            <div class="block-children">
              <div class="block-container" style="position: relative;"></div>
              <br>
              <div class="block-container" style="position: relative;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="block-container" style="position: relative;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS includes the following:

```
.block-group {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: flex!important;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

As you can see from the preview, you can nest AND blocks.  In the demo, the child AND block does not take up the full width of the container, but the parent does.  I would like for the width of all AND blocks, indicated by the border, to only take up the required space.  How can I make the parent AND block from taking up the full width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `display` it as `inline-flex`, then it will only take the contents width:

```
.block-group {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: inline-flex !important;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```